# UnMarshal a CSV file using Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

This is my sample code to unmarshal a csv file using Apache Camel.
The issue is that it is not picking up the file from location file://src/test/resources/?&fileName=test.csv and not generating the result in list "Result".

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() {
        List result=new ArrayList();
        //from("file://src/test/resources/?&fileName=test.csv").unmarshal().csv().to(result);
        from("file://src/test/resources/").unmarshal().csv().to("file://src/test/res1/");
   }
});
ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

context.start();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    template.sendBody("file://src/test/resources/", "this is Test Message: " + i);
    System.out.println("hi");
}

Thread.sleep(1000);
context.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code `from("file://src/test/resources/?&fileName=test.csv").unmarshal().csv().to(result);` shall not work. I guess camel context wont even start since the `to` does not have a valid endpoint. Instead your route should be

```
from("file://src/test/resources/?&fileName=test.csv").unmarshal().csv().process(new Processor() { public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 
String csvContent =  exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
// access the result arrayList and store the csvContent.

result.add(csvContent); 
}
```